# View clipboard contents

Tags: excel, dojo, clipboard, copy-paste

Does anyone out there know how I can view what's actually being copied from Microsoft Excel when I select a set of cells an click "copy"?

I would like to see what, if any, styles, html, etc are actually being copied from the product. I am extending Dojo's Rich Text Editor and need to make sure that when the data is pasted, it is properly pasted into the editor.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to view the "end user value" like the windows clipboard viewer?  Or do you want to see the actual data behind the scenes?

Comment: The actual data behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with a quick java application.

If anyone is interested in this, please reply to this answer.